# Изменение текста в label c# и utf8

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу изменить содержимое label с клавиатуры, причем иных компонентов у меня нет, исключительно один *label1* . 
Вот что я имею:

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cancoding == true)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
                    if (label1.Text != "")
                        label1.Text = label1.Text.Substring(0, label1.Text.Length - 1);
                    else
                        return;
                else
                    label1.Text += ((char)e.KeyCode).ToString();
            }
}
```

Сия код отлавливает все клавиши, но если я захочу ввести с клавиатуры к примеру *:* или захочу написать любой русский текст или просто нажать на кнопки *shift,alt,CAPSLOCK* он выводит непонятную дичь, не являющаяся читабельным текстом.
Очень прошу помочь

Comment: У KeyEventArgs есть куча "пропертей", которые сигнализируют какая из комбинация управляющих клавиш нажата. Соответственно, зная что нажали, дальше Вы можете уже правильно конвертировать Value в нужный string

Comment: Вся проблема в этом `label1.Text += ((char)e.KeyCode).ToString();` вы не отделяете печатные символы от непечатных (shift, alt ...), перед отображением нужно отделять мух от котлет.

Answer (score 1):

Написание редактора текста с нуля, на самом деле, непростая задача. И проблема, упомянутая в вопросе, не единственная которая возникнет. Первое что приходит на ум (но это актуально лишь для стран вроде Японии или Китая) - поддержка ввода через IME. Из актуальных проблем, поддержка выделения, копирования, вставки и замены.

Поэтому я рекомендую для редактирования текста временно создавать TextBox и помещать его точно над Label. После нажатия определенной комбинации клавиш (допустим Enter или CTRL+ENTER), копировать текст из TextBox в Label и уничтожать TextBox.

Если все же использовать подход описанный в вопросе, то можно воспользоваться решением данным на аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном Stack Overflow: [Convert keycode to char/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170259/convert-keycode-to-char-string). Я имею ввиду непринятый автором вопроса ответ, набравший наибольшее количество голосов.

В ответе предлагается использовать функцию Win API ToUnicode. Для этого, ее необходимо импортировать:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int ToUnicode(
    uint virtualKeyCode, 
    uint scanCode,
    byte[] keyboardState,
    StringBuilder receivingBuffer, 
    int bufferSize, 
    uint flags
);
```

Автором приводится так же пример использования этой функции, который учитывает смену регистра нажатием Shift (но не учитывает Caps Lock).

```
static string GetCharsFromKeys(Keys keys, bool shift)    
{
    var buf = new StringBuilder(256);
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];
    if (shift)
    {
        keyboardState[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;
    }
        ToUnicode((uint)keys, 0, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0);
        return buf.ToString();
}
```